# OpenCV OCL Error: GPU API call (-1001) in initializeOpenCLDevices

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencl, ocl

I've been using some OpenCV for a while now and I'm just starting to delve into the multi threading aspects although I'm having some difficulty getting the following code to work:

```
#include "opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    cv::ocl::DevicesInfo devices;
    cv::ocl::getOpenCLDevices(devices, cv::ocl::CVCL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU);

    return 0;
}
```

Returns

> OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (-1001) in initializeOpenCLDevices, file /path/to/opencv/src/opencv-2.4.9/modules/ocl/src/cl_context.cpp, line 455

I definitely built OpenCV with OCL, if I go into my build directory it has the lib files: libopencv_ocl.so etc. and I checked with ldd to make sure the executable was linking correctly.

Note: the same thing happens when I try the:

```
cv::ocl::getOpenCLPlatforms
```

function.

Thanks in advance

[OpenCV OCL API Link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/structures_and_utility_functions.html#ocl-initializecontext)

Comment: Error `-1001` indicates that the OpenCL ICD loader failed to find any OpenCL platforms on your system. Which OpenCL platform(s) are you using?

Comment: How do I check? I installed OpenCL through ubuntu synaptic package manager

Comment: Which package did you install? That was probably just the OpenCL ICD loader. You actually need some real OpenCL platforms, e.g. from NVIDIA, Intel or AMD. What device are you trying to run on?

Comment: Intel to start me off then I would like to use NVidia

Comment: The packages I installed were: opencl, opencl-headers, nvidia-opencl-dev and python-pyopencl I can't see any other packages for Intel

Answer (score 0):

The Intel OpenCL runtime is not available from the Ubuntu package manager; you need to download and install it from their website:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#philinux